# add a div.class in a child, only when the parent does not have other div.class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a html code like this:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="checkclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="checkclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="checkclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
</div>
```

and i need to add a div only on those divs that dont have that "checkclass", so it will like this:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="checkclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="newclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="checkclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="checkclass"></div>
</div>
<div class="someclass">
    <div class="childclass"></div>
    <div class="newclass"></div>
</div>
```

i tried with jquery something like:

```
$('.someclase:not(children(hasClass(checkclass))').append('<div class="newclass"></div>');
$('.someclass:not(:children(.checkclass))').append('<div class="newclass"></div>');
$('.someclass > :not(.checkclass)').append('<div class="newclass"></div>');
```

but still nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$(".someclass").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).find(".checkclass").length)
    {
        $(this).append("<div class='checkclass' />");
    }
});
```

What you tried is getting all elements that not have the checkclass class. Not the DIV's that don't have a child with checkclass.

Comment: I was just about to post almost exactly the same code :p, although you may want to be careful with self closing div, I seem to recall some browsers don't like them (but I may have made that up).

Comment: If you don't put the closing `/` IE7 won't add the DIV because then it's not valid. This works in all browsers I tested (IE7+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera).

Comment: Ok, I thought you needed a full </div> to close it, as you do with </script>

Answer (score 0):

[Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is a good solution for this:

```
$('div.someclass').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('div.checkclass').length === 0;
}).append('<div class="newclass"></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/GKgc9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        $('.someclass').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).find('.checkclass').length){
                $(this).append('<div class="newclass">Test</div>');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':not .checkclass').closest('.someclass');
```

or

```
$('.someclass').not( $('.checkclass').closest('.someclass') );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!$(someClass).hasClass(checkClass)) {
    $(someClass).addClass(newClass);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.